# Spring Test mockMvc is ignoring validation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, spring-test, mockmvc

please help me to solve the following issue:
I have a class, where several fields are marked as @NotNull:

```
public class SearchCommentRequest {

@NotNull
private Date fromDate;

@NotNull
private Date toDate;

//...
}
```

Object if this class is passed to controller as @RequestBody annotated also with @Valid:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/comment/search", consumes="application/json", produces = "text/csv")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> searchComments(@RequestBody @Valid SearchCommentRequest searchRequest) {
    List<SearchCommentResult> comments = commentService.searchComments(searchRequest);
```

So, I expect that if either fromDate or toDate is null - exception will be thrown.

Writing my integration tests, I decided to check this validation case as well:

```
@Test
public void searchCommentsValidateRequest() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SearchCommentRequest request = new SearchCommentRequest();
    // toDate = null; 
    request.setFromDate(new Date());
    String requestBody = mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(request);

    mockMvc.perform(post(COMMENT_SEARCH_ENDPOINT)
            .contentType("application/json")
            .content(requestBody))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(status().is(400));
}
```

But it looks like mockMvc is ignoring validation. Searching for the same issues, I found several sources where solution was adding the following dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But it didn't help.
I'm using Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE and manually added to pom.xml the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @Notnull is often use at entity level.
It will validate and throw exception when you persist entity automatically.

If you want to validate at controller and use @Valid.

You should declare more about BindingResult result

and check errors

```
if(result.hasErrors()){
//do something or throw exceptions
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've added @Valid to the property level to work in conjunction with NotNull, but the issue still persists, mockMvc is ignoring validation.
BindingResult is the next step I think, it gives you a mechanism to decide what to do if validation error happened. As for now I don't need any custom logic, I just want the regular validation Exception to be thrown.

Comment: Spring validator will validate your object and pass the result to bindingresult.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/
It don't throw exceptions here except you check and iterate error objects in binding result and throws exception.

Comment: Not true, even without bindingresult org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException is thrown. Bidningresult is giving you a possibility to decide what to do with the errors (even ignore them), but it doesn't mean that without bindingresult no exception is thrown.

Comment: I solved it by adding the following dependency: org.hibernate.validator / hibernate-validator